# Why bash cannot accept option of command as string?

Tags: bash

I tried following code.

```
command1="echo"
"${command1}" 'case1'

command2="echo -e"
"${command2}" 'case2'

echo -e 'case3'
```

The outputs are following,

```
case1
echo -e: command not found
case3
```

The case2 results in an error but similar cases, case1 and case3 runs well. It seems command with option cannot be recognized as valid command.

I would like to know why it does not work. Please teach me. Thank you very much.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Case 1 (Unmodified)

> ```
> command1="echo"
> "${command1}" 'case1'
> ```

This is bad practice as an idiom, but there's nothing actively incorrect about it.

---

#### Case 2 (Unmodified)

> ```
> command2="echo -e"
> "${command2}" 'case2'
> ```

This is looking for a program named something like `/usr/bin/echo -e`, **with the space as part of its name**.

---

#### Case 2 (Reduced Quotes)

```
# works in this very specific case, but bad practice
command2="echo -e"
$command2 'case2' # WITHOUT THE QUOTES
```

...this one works, but only because your command isn't interesting enough (doesn't have quotes, doesn't have backslashes, doesn't have other shell syntax). See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for a description of why it isn't an acceptable practice in general.

---

#### Case X (`eval` -- Bad Practice, Oft Advised)

You'll often see this:

```
eval "$command1 'case1'"
```

...in this very specific case, where `command1` and all arguments are hardcoded, this isn't exceptionally harmful. However, it's *extremely* harmful with only a small change:

```
# SECURITY BUGS HERE
eval "$command1 ${thing_to_echo}"
```

...if `thing_to_echo='$(rm -rf $HOME)'`, you'll have a very bad day.

---

#### Best Practices

In general, commands shouldn't be stored in strings. Use a function:

```
e() { echo -e "$@"; }
e "this works"
```

...or, if you need to build up your argument list incrementally, an array:

```
e=( echo -e )
"${e[@]}" "this works"
```

---

#### Aside: On `echo -e`

Any implementation of  `echo` where `-e` does anything other than emit the characters `-e` on output [is failing to comply with the relevant POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html), which recommends using `printf` instead (see the APPLICATION USAGE section).

Consider instead:

```
# a POSIX-compliant alternative to bash's default echo -e
e() { printf '%b\n' "$*"; }
```

...this not only gives you compatibility with non-bash shells, but also fixes support for bash in POSIX mode if compiled with `--enable-xpg-echo-default` or `--enable-usg-echo-default`, or if `shopt -s xpg_echo` was set, or if `BASHOPTS=xpg_echo` was present in the shell's environment at startup time.

Comment: thank you for answering and providing instructions. Honestly, it seems that the problem of running command contained by variable is too complicated for me. I just avoid using it. Thank you again.

Comment: Thank to your instruction above and BashFAQ #50 , it seems command loaded by array can avoid the problem with string variable. I will use the array. Thank you again.

Comment: The shell is not *“looking for a program named something like /usr/bin/echo -e”* it is searching for a command exactly called `echo -e`, the exact string, in the PATH.

Comment: @sorontar, yup. And the text you've quoted, I'd argue, makes that point even to someone unclear on the finer elements.

Answer (score 2):

If the variable `command` contains the value `echo -e`.
And the command line given to the shell is:

```
"$command" 'case2'
```

The shell will search for a command called `echo -e` with spaces included.
That command doesn't exist and the shell reports the error.

The reason of why this happen is depicted in [the image linked below, from O'Reilly's Learning the Bash Shell, 3rd Edition](http://helios.cs.ifmo.ru/~ad/Documentation/Bash_Shell/bash3-CHP-7-SECT-3.html):

```
Learning the bash Shell, 3rd Edition
By Cameron Newham
...............................................
Publisher: O'Reilly
Pub Date: March 2005
ISBN: 0-596-00965-8
Pages: 352
```

If the variable is quoted (follow the right arrows) it goes almost (passing steps 6,7, and 8) directly to execution in step 12.
Therefore, the command searched has not been split on spaces.

Original image (removed because of @CharlesDuffy complaint, I don't agree, but ok, let's move to the impossible to be in fault side) is here:

[Link to original image in the web site where I found it.](http://helios.cs.ifmo.ru/~ad/Documentation/Bash_Shell/bash3-CHP-7-SECT-3.html)

If the command line given to the shell is un-quoted:

```
$command 'case2'
```

The string `command` gets expanded in step 6 (Parameter expansion) and then the value of the variable `$command`: `echo -e` gets divided in step 9: "Word splitting".
Then the shell search for command `echo` with argument `-e`.
The command `echo` "see" an argument of `-e` and echo process it as an option.

Trying to store commands inside an string is a very bad idea.
Try this, think very carefully of what you would expect the out put to be, and then be surprised on execution:

```
$ command='echo -e case2; echo "next line"'; $command
```

To take a look  at what happens, execute the command as this:

```
$ set -vx; $command; set +vx
```

Comment: Very nice. Where's that diagram from?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Looks like it's from the book "[Learning the Korn Shell](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/ksh/ch07_03.htm)"...

Comment: @sorontar : Thank you for perfect diagram. This is the first time I can understand what happens on parsing by shell as process line.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The diagram is similar to the one from the book, but is not valid for ksh, it is specific for **bash** (as tagged in the question).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The link to the source has been added to the answer. Again, it is : http://helios.cs.ifmo.ru/~ad/Documentation/Bash_Shell/bash3-CHP-7-SECT-3.html

Comment: Okay -- that link is from Learning the Bash Shell, 3rd Edition, written by Cameron Newham and published by O'Reilly. Edited to apply credit (whether reuse is within terms of the license on that media is a separate question altogether).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy As the book is from USA, I believe their "Fair Use" applies. And I also believe that this use is "Fair Use". It is used for "public’s interest"(http://www.socialmediaexaminer.com/copyright-fair-use-and-how-it-works-for-online-images/) as *“teaching (including multiple copies for classroom use)”*. Of course IANAL (I Am Not A Lawyer), But Please read all and specially scenario 7 on [this page](http://www.thebookdesigner.com/2010/02/what-every-writer-ought-to-know-about-fair-use-and-copyright/).

Comment: @sorontar, I'm not a lawyer either, but I did take a few semesters of law classes. Fair use is a *defense* -- it won't stop you from being sued, but it can stop you from losing a suit; that doesn't mean that lawsuit isn't time and trouble you don't want. Moreover, the test is a balancing act: Educational use is a point against, but there are other items that apply: If the reuse decreases the size of the commercial market for the publication, for instance, that's a point *against* fair use being applicable.

Comment: @sorontar, ... Which points are powerful enough to overcome which other points depends, in large part, on judicial discretion: Which judge you get, and how they're inclined to weigh the various factors. In consequence, a result is rarely cut-and-dried.

Comment: @sorontar, ...anyhow, in this particular case, the [StackOverflow TOS](http://stackexchange.com/legal) is arguably applicable: *Subscriber represents, warrants and agrees that it will not contribute any Subscriber Content that (a) infringes, violates or otherwise interferes with any copyright or trademark of another party, [...] (c) infringes any intellectual property right of another or the privacy or publicity rights of another, [..], or (f) remains posted after Subscriber has been notified that such Subscriber Content violates any of sections (a) to (e) of this sentence.*

Comment: ...if you have questions on the point, we could take this to [meta].

Comment: To be clear, by the way -- this is a good answer; I'm one of your upvotes. But I also think that including content from a published book without acknowledging the author and publisher was sketchy, *potentially* sketchy enough to be a TOS violation.

Comment: ...and with my intellectual-property-law-hobbyist hat on, I think your attempt to draw a parallel with Example 7 on your linked page is... well, frankly, missing the point. Example 7 *is* a winning case, but that's not because the use is for education, but because the use is for critical commentary on a matter of public interest. That doesn't apply here: The content isn't essential to making the point; a completely new diagram drawn from scratch showing the same parser (in a different style, &c) would have sufficed just as well, and the use at hand *isn't* commentary at all.

Comment: ...instead of being commentary, the pertinent use is education, and *that puts that use in direct competition with the author of the original text, which is being sold into the same market*, which is (as aforementioned) a point against fair use being applicable. If you were quoting part of a work of fiction to use for educational purposes, then that factor would weigh in your favor instead -- your use wouldn't be competing with the publisher's use -- but such isn't the case here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Fine, to the point. What are you asking me to do? (but before you answer update your browser view of the this page.).

Comment: If you're interested in finding a diagram on a similar topic available for public use, http://stuff.lhunath.com/parser.png is written by @lhunath -- who perhaps can clarify permissions for us directly here. The diagram in [Chet Ramey's chapter of The Architecture of Open Source Applications](http://aosabook.org/en/bash.html) may also be useful, and is under the [Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/legalcode) license.

Answer (score -1):

It works on my machine if I give the command this way:

```
cmd2="echo -e"
```

if you are still facing a problem I would suggest storing the options in another variable so that if you are doing shell scripting then multiple commands that use similar option values you can leverage the variable so also try something like this.

```
cmd1="echo"
opt1="-e"
$cmd1 $opt1 Hello
```

Comment: `$cmd1 $opt1 Hello` has almost all the same bugs as `$cmd2 Hello` (except for sensitivity to an `IFS` without whitespace). If you had `IFS=' -'`, for instance, it would become `echo e Hello`. `"$cmd1" "$opt1" Hello` would avoid that, but it's a lot of extra work/typing for the user.